# Display 3 background urls to 3 different div classes

Tags: css

I'm trying to display three different background images (that turn into GIF's on hover) on 3 distinct divs all with different class names. Essentially, the last two are working properly and the first one isn't showing up at all. Code displayed below. I've tried giving the first one an id, it still won't show up. I've tried putting the first .recipe selector last in the CSS, it still won't show up. After researching CSS specificity I chained a bunch selectors to increase it's specificity. Perhaps there is something outside of this block of code interfering with it? I inspected the div not working (.recipe) and indeed I can see the rules aren't applying to it, I just can't determine why, and why applying an ID to it does not solve the issue. I would appreciate any thoughts. Thanks in advance

```css
.recipe{
        height: 200px;
        width: auto;
        background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498837167922-ddd27525d352?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
        margin:1em; 
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        transition: transform .2s;
    }
    
.recipe:hover {
        cursor:pointer; 
            background:url('https://github.com/dkennedy533/Recipes/blob/gh-pages/Recipes%20Demo.gif?raw=true');
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            transform: scale(1.38); 
    }

.gif2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    background: url("https://neilpatel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/colors.jpg");
    margin:1em; 
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transition: transform .17s;
}

.gif2:hover {
    cursor:pointer; 
    background:url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dkennedy533/Color-Guessing-Game/master/Color%20Game%20GIF.gif');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transform: scale(1.4); 
}

.gif3{
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    background: url("https://img.nbc.com/sites/nbcunbc/files/images/2016/1/19/MDot-TheOffice-640x360-MP.jpg");
    margin:1em; 
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transition: transform .17s;
}

.gif3:hover {
    cursor:pointer; 
    background:url('https://github.com/dkennedy533/The-office/blob/master/office%20reording.gif?raw=true');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transform: scale(1.4); 
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
        <p>Hover over the sections below to preview the application. Click to visit the app.</p> <hr>
        <div class="features"> 

            <h2>Recipe Search Engine</h2>
            <p>React, Node.JS, CSS, Public API used for database</p>
            <a href="https://dkennedy533.github.io/Recipes/">
            <div class="recipe">
                
    
                </div></a><hr>      

            <h2>Color Guessing Game</h2>
            <p>HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery</p>
            <a href="https://dkennedy533.github.io/Color-Guessing-Game/" target="_blank">
                
                <div class = "gif2" >

                </div></a><hr>
    
            <h2>The Office Quotes</h2>
            <p>HTML, CSS, JS</p>
            <a href="https://dkennedy533.github.io/The-office/" target="_blank">

                <div class ="gif3" >
            

                </div></a><hr>              
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: your code works well. at least here

Comment: You're right. That should indicate to me that the problem is outside of the snippet I've provided and somewhere else in the program. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm just not sure what else in the program would affect only the first div of that list.

Comment: Yes, then the problem is outside of this code here. Pay attention to the html structure of this place in your project. Maybe you missed a tag.